# bootstrap datatable sorting not working properly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables, frontend

I am using bootstrap **datatable**, when I click on sorting icon on second column then only it removes icon from first column, otherwise it **appears** on page load, I have written column number to remove from ordering in code but not working.

```
   $('#example').DataTable( {

  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": [0,1],
    "orderable": false
  },

  { "width": "8%", "targets": 0 },
  { "width": "13%", "targets": 1 } ],


  initComplete: function () {

    this.api().columns().every( function () {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
      .on( 'change', function () {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
         $(this).val()
         );

        column
        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
        .draw();
      } );

      column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
      } );
    } );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Datatables uses the first column as ordering by default, and thus renders the icon that states which column is the one providing the ordering. If you want to remove it then you have to provide an explicit ordering in your configuration, such as:
        `order: [[1, 'asc']],`
which will use the second column as default ordering.